# Hook on opening a media/document

Tags: hooks, filesystem

I am trying to find a hook to be able to set a datalayer.push everytime a document is opened.

It could even be something that runs after the document is opened
ex: https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/pdf-document.pdf

And if it can trigger only on pdf files, it would be even better.

Does it exist? Or how can I create one?

Thanks!

Comment: WordPress doesn't really load at all whenever you access a media file directly by URL, as described above. You would likely need to add an HTAccess rule and route the request through a PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to find a hook to be able to set a datalayer.push everytime a document is opened.
>
> It could even be something that runs after the document is opened ex: https://proximite-courtage.fr/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/LISTE_PARTENAIRES_PC_22062022.pdf

**No.**

WP isn't running when you visit PDF files directly via their URL, so there is no PHP loaded and no opportunities for WordPress hooks

> Does it exist? Or how can I create one?

In the olden days the `wp-content/uploads` folder was handled by an `ms-files.php`, which *might* have provided you this possibility in *some* cases. However it had large performance problems, is incompatible with a lot of CDNs and caching systems.

Most importantly of all:

- it would only work the first time due to browser cache
- it's deprecated and only present for legacy reasons.

**If you did use this, and worked around the problems, the resulting hook would be extremely unreliable.**

If you want to fire off an analytics event when a user visits and opens a PDF you have these options:

- you need to indicate the PDF can never be cached in the headers
- you need to handle the loading and sending of the PDF yourself

  - you'll need special Apache/Nginx rules to reroute the request to your custom bespoke application ( highly likely that this will not be a WordPress application )
- you would need to investigate options for the PDF phoning home, as well as the legal and regulatory ramifications, as anybody could save and share the PDF

  - all these protections can be bypassed using the print dialog, either to physical paper, or the print to PDF option

The easiest option is to never link to the PDF and instead display it inside the web page.

***But most important of all, you need to come to terms with the fact that no matter what you do, no matter what system you use, you will never get a reliable analytics signal that your PDF was opened, and you will **always** record fewer openings than actually happened.***

Comment: Hi Tom, Thank you very much for this exhaustive answer!
So I think I'll have to work with the links, and add a class that triggers the script. My problem is that the customer will have to add the class each time they add a new link, and I also have to pass the name of the file.

Comment: most people get around this by never linking to the PDFs but putting them in a reader/iframe on a page and sharing that page, or using a download page where you can watch the download button. Of course you're not really tracking the PDF but the page it's on, so sharing the PDF, printing, downloading and copying all bypass this, but that's true of any solution you find. The best most foolproof solution there is, is to not use PDFs or other documents that are fungible/copyable. HTML docs can be dynamically rendered at runtime with tracking

Comment: Yep but I would need to track every document and the best case scenario would be that they get automaticaly added to the list of tracked documents.